# facebook share Fb.ui description line break

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I have using fb share for my website but i have one problem for fb.ui "description" not line break

Here is my code please help me

```
<script>
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() {     
        FB.init({
            appId      : '****************',
            status     : true,
            xfbml      : true
        });
        // Code in here will run once FB has been initialised
        function FB_post_feed(method,name,link,picture,caption,description){
            FB.ui({
                method: method,
                name: name,
                link: link,
                picture: picture,
                caption: caption,
                description: description
            });
        }
     };
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on("click","a.share-btn",function(){
                FB.ui({
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: 'Test',
                    link: 'http:/test.com',
                    picture: 'http://test.com/public/images/logo.png',
                    caption: 'testing purspose',
                    description: 'my script run succesfully.\n But decsription not line break.\n please help me!'
                });

            });
});
```

Comment: the other thread is about the send dialog, not the feed dialog. but they behave the same way, it´s not possible (anymore). earlier it was possible with a trick (<center></center>, sor something like that).

Comment: thanks for reply me!
ya exactly i was also used <center></center> but not worked.
any other option for facebook sharing?

Comment: no, there is no other option.